# How use GROUP BY and MAX on Strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to group the following table.

[image]

I want to group the table with Department_ID and Employee_ID, and display the team that occurs the most. The goal table should look like this:

[image: future_state_table]

```
SELECT [Department_ID]
      ,[Employee_ID]
      , max(team_id)
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[dbo].[table]
GROUP BY 
       [Department_ID]
      ,[Employee_ID]
```

But i do not get the expected results.

[image]

Try it out: https://dbfiddle.uk/2HHLZQe-

Comment:  Please provide your sample data as text, not as [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. Clue - you're using *max* and "B" is the maximum value when ordered alphabetically, you are asking to *count* rows.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: add `Team_ID` to  the group (because you want the highest number (=`count()`)  per Team, order descending, and select `TOP 1`  ?

Comment: Group by Department_ID and Employee_ID and display the team that occurs the most, dynamicljy.

Comment: You could look into the "Partition by, order by" functions.
https://blog.quest.com/when-and-how-to-use-the-sql-partition-by-clause/

Comment: @HenrikClausen maybe, but how to use it.

Comment: What would you expect if there were 4 IDs 2 `A` and 2 `B`

Comment: @Stu good qestion, random choose one.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/2HHLZQe-

Comment: I can use min but it does not show me the most occured value in the colum of team_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways you could do this, the de-facto solution is to use a row_number window:

```
with c as (
    select Department_ID, Employee_ID, Team_ID, Count(Team_ID) q
    from t
    group by Department_ID, Employee_ID, Team_ID
), rn as (
    select Department_ID, Employee_ID, Team_ID, 
      Row_Number() over(partition by Department_ID, Employee_ID order by q desc) rn
    from c
)
select Department_ID, Employee_ID, Team_ID as most_occured_values
from rn
where rn = 1;
```

Pointed out by @Charlieface this can be more compactly expressed as follows - I'll leave the above as it helps illustrate the process

```
with c as (
  select
    Department_ID,
    Employee_ID,
    Team_ID,
    Count(*) q,
    Row_Number() over(partition by Department_ID, Employee_ID order by count(*) desc) rn
  from t
  group by Department_ID, Employee_ID, Team_ID
)
select Department_ID, Employee_ID, Team_ID as most_occured_values
from c
where rn = 1;
```

Modified [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4kSyZLNE)

Comment: You can do that in a single CTE https://dbfiddle.uk/4kSyZLNE also `COUNT(Team_ID)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` if not null

Answer (score 0):

I just added a MIN function it isn't the best solution but works.

```
SELECT*
FROM [dbo].[table]

SELECT [Department_ID]
  ,[Employee_ID]
  , MIN(team_id) as most_occured_values
FROM [dbo].[table]
GROUP BY 
   [Department_ID]
  ,[Employee_ID]
```

Comment: they show the right answer, but it is not a solid good. SQL has no intent to delivery the most used column.

Comment: im messing around trying to find out a good solution

Answer (score 0):

--Check this

```
Select [Department_ID],[Employee_ID],[Team_ID] ,counts 
from (Select [Department_ID],[Employee_ID],[Team_ID],Count(*) counts,Row_number () over (Partition by [Department_ID],[Employee_ID] Order by Count(*) desc) TeamIDCount
From #temp
Group by [Department_ID],[Employee_ID],[Team_ID])T
Where TeamIDCount=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TOP 1 department_id ,employee_id ,team_id 
FROM 
(
SELECT Department_ID,Employee_ID, count(team_id) as COUNT,team_id
FROM  TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY Department_ID,Employee_ID,team_id ) t
ORDER BY COUNT desc
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.